# Is it possible to disable dropbox notifications for app folder

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

I'm playing around with `dropbox.js` and have created a web-app to take notes and save them to my dropbox account.

Is there a possibility to turn off notifications for only this one App folder without turning off all notifications?

Comment: It's not possible to switch off notifications for just one folder (or more). The only way to do it is to stop syncing this folder (Preferences > Advanced > Selective sync) which is not your goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These days, with API v2, you can mute notifications on individual upload operations via the `mute` parameter on /files/upload.

See https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-upload for the detailed API documentation.